# How can I force CKEditor to launch in full screen?

Tags: php, ckeditor

CKEditor lets you click a toolbar button to "Maximize" the textarea. I want to do this automatically when the page loads. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try below code:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', { /*Editor instance configuration goes here*/ });
editor.on( 'instanceReady', function(event){
    if(event.editor.getCommand( 'maximize' ).state == CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_OFF);//ckeck if maximize is off
        event.editor.execCommand( 'maximize');
});
```